# Define default annotation

Tags: kotlin, annotations

is there a way to extend/define an annotation in Kotlin?
To be more specific, in my code I might want to use `@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)` a number of times. Can I define an annotation like `@NormalizedRange` that equals `@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you can try annotating `@NormalizedRange` with `@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)`.

Comment: Aside from this, you can always use default values for `from` and `to`.

Comment: @dan1st thank you for responding
I tried it like this
`@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)
annotation class NormalRange`

and in my code use it like `fun foo(@NormalRange percent: Float) ...`
but it didn't through an error with values outside the range. 
What do you mean by "default values for `from` and `to`?

Comment: `annotation class FloatRange(val from=0.0,val to=1.0)`